# Trying to work with while loop in shell script which is causing infinite loop

Tags: loops, unix, while-loop

```
# !/bin/sh
i=1
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do 
  echo $i
  i= 'expr $i + 1'
done
```

example program to display the numbers from 1 to 9..but it is entering into infinite loop while executing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the line

```
i= 'expr $i + 1'
```

with

```
i=`expr $i + 1`
```

u used (') symbol but it is 'back quote symbol'(above tab button)and dont give space between '=' and '`'
[click here for code](http://ideone.com/cE0FEg)

Answer (score 1):

Your incrementation is causing the problem. Try this:

```
# !/bin/sh
i=1
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do 
  echo $i
  i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```